# Remove empty attributes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Im trying to sort all elements, then attributes, which ive got working, however i cant figure out for the life of me how to remove attributes that are empty

Here is the sort XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:apply-templates >
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*[*]">

    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" >
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" >
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Attributes have no order in XML, so don't count on the order being always as expected.

Comment: no im sorting by alphabetical order, and not intrested in thier index position

Comment: the point is that depending on the destination of the transform (e.g. the XmlWriter implementation), the order of the attributes written doesn't have to always correspond to the order you're specifying. I'm just making you aware of this fact.

Comment: Oh yea thanks, i know, but im actually sorting two xml files, which i need to run a `diff` for, therefore order to me is important for this task. However i agree the order of attributes in XML does not matter.

Comment: I'm referring to the [XML spec, section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags): "Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant." - this means that every implementation can choose to write attributes in any order, it's "luck" if it works in your case and may break at any time if the underlying writer is changed/updated (e.g. update of the Framework version).

Comment: Yes i get it @Lucero, but i know the output of the two xml's is exactly the same. All im trying to do is to run a diff, on two xmls, Where the first xml omits empty attributes, and the new xml leaves them in with blanks. This is just for testing purposes, and I understand the Spec section 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the only place where you process attribute nodes is `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*">` so changing that to `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*[normalize-space()]">` might suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.)!=0">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()"> <!-- replaces the "match='@* | node()'" template -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates >
            <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I did something similar to this earlier, it didnt work. however i didnt use `string-length` so plus one :D